# Usage of "у них у всех" vs "у них всех"

Tags: словоупотребление

In conversation, I just said:

> Некоторых ссор время от времени просто не избежать. **У них у всех** ведь  нет ничего общего.

Nuance-wise, how does the dual-prepositional-style "у них у всех" sound, compared to "**у них всех**"? More emphatic?

The same goes for "у вас у двоих" vs "у вас двоих" or "к ним ко всем" vs "к ним всем" etc.

Answer (score 3):

I never use **у вас у двоих**, but do use **к ним ко всем**, the reason could be to avoid difficulty of articulating clusters of consonants ***ни***-***`хвс`***-***ех***, ***ни***-***`мвс`***-***ем***, especially the last because both **M** and **B** are labials, but the pronunciation of a cluster in ***ва***-***`сдв`***-***оих***, ***ни***-***`хдв`***-***оих*** doesn't present any difficulty.

Placing preposition before each member of **`adjective + noun`** (**на новых на ботинках**), **`possessive pronoun + noun`** (**у наших у ворот**), **`indicative pronoun + noun`** (**за тем за полем**) collocations (and even oftener in reverse order of members) is a traditional device of Russian folklore and then poetry whose purpose is most likely to either make verses more melodic by breaking clusters of consonants (as in the case of folklore) or to make them conform to the meter by means of lengthening and syllabic multiplication.

<sup>***Further reading:*** [О ПОВТОРЕ ПРЕДЛОГОВ ПЕРЕД ОДНОРОДНЫМИ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯМИ В СОВРЕМЕННОМ РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ: ОПЫТ КОРПУСНОГО АНАЛИЗА *by Сатюкова Дарья Николаeвна*](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/o-povtore-predlogov-pered-odnorodnymi-opredeleniyami-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke-opyt-korpusnogo-analiza)</sup>

Comment: This is not just the folklore, this was the way Old Russian language (and in fact most Slavic languages) worked. The absence of this feature in Church Slavonic, which had later spread to Russian, is generally attributed to Greek influence.

Comment: I see. What about nuances of meaning?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens there're no nuances whatsoever other than the fact that this is a feature of colloquial language